# Cannot parse FormData into django backend

Tags: javascript, python, django, ajax, forms

hope you all are doing well I have been working on a custom form that I want to send to django backend via ajax request, the only problem that I am encountering is I am wrapping the form into FormData it works well on the frontend site but on the backend it shows a querydict with some strane data in it and making it much harder to parse the data, if there can be a way to easily get the data out.

Any leads or any response is much appreciated

Following is my code of the javascript function that sends the data to the backend

#### Javascript

```
function Edit_Content(e){
    
    var form_data=new FormData(document.querySelector("#edit-form"))
    let csrftoken=getCookie("csrftoken")
    
    $.ajax({
      url:"{% url 'EditPost' %}",
      method:"post",
      datatype:"json",
      processData:false,
      "headers":{
          "X-CSRFToken":csrftoken
        },
      data:form_data,
      success:function (data){
        console.log("Post or idea edited")
      }
    })
    
  }
```

#### views.py

```
def Edit(request):
    print(request.POST,request.FILES)
    data=dict(request.POST)
    print(data)
    if data["type"] == "post":
        post=Post.objects.get(pk=data['id'])
        content=data.get("post-content",None)
        media=data.get("media",None)
        post.edit(content,media)
    else:
        idea=Idea.objects.get(pk=data["id"])
        title=data.get("title",None)
        privacy=data.get("privacy",None)
        requirements=data.get("requirements",None)
        category=data.get("category",None)
        content=data.get("idea-content",None)
        media=data.get("media",None)
        idea.edit(requirements,title,privacy,category,content,media)
    return HttpResponse(status=200)
```

After converting request.POST into dictionary object it it gives

```
{'------WebKitFormBoundaryW30RtYeVz4cXnUNf\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name': ['"type"\r\n\r\nidea\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryW30RtYeVz4cXnUNf\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="id"\r\n\r\n1\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryW30RtYeVz4cXnUNf\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="title"\r\n\r\nProgramming is great\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryW30RtYeVz4cXnUNf\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="privacy"\r\n\r\n public\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryW30RtYeVz4cXnUNf\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="requirements"\r\n\r\nnothing\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryW30RtYeVz4cXnUNf\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="category"\r\n\r\nFisica\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryW30RtYeVz4cXnUNf\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="idea-content"\r\n\r\nProgramming is not for kids\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryW30RtYeVz4cXnUNf\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="media"; filename=""\r\nContent-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryW30RtYeVz4cXnUNf--\r\n']}
```

Which is hard to parse with the regex, is there any easier way to do this?

The form is being added dynamically but the basic structure of the form is as follows:

#### HTML form

```
<form id="edit-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            
</form>
```

Comment: removing processData:false gives an error of illegal invocation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem myself by manually iterating over each input field of the form and serializing it.

The javascript code looks like this

```
    var form_data=new FormData()
    $("form#edit-form :input").each(function(){
    var input = this; // This is the jquery object of the input, do what you will
    console.log(input)
    if(this.name == "media"){
      form_data.append(this.name,this.files[0])
    }
    else{
      form_data.append(this.name,this.value)
    }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

request.POST is a dictionary-like object but is not your standard dictionary.

you can access normal textual data by using this notation.

```py
data = request.POST

title=data.get("title",None)
privacy=data.get("privacy",None)
requirements=data.get("requirements",None)
category=data.get("category",None)
content=data.get("idea-content",None)
```

alternatively

```
title = request.POST.get("title", None)
```

POST does not include file-upload information, so you would need to call a different request property to access them.

```
request.FILES.get('media')
```

Comment: I normally do the same thing, but sending the form using Formdata is giving that weird dict with all the data wrapped around unnecessary string which is not giving request.POST a normal dictionary-like object

Comment: That will work if you are only dealing with text data. But you are also trying to upload a file with that form data.

Comment: Maybe you are missing the multipart enctype property in your form data

Comment: multipart/form-data is also added into the form